# Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, net

Algunas veces funciona la aplicación y otras veces genera el error

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost:49336/api/Usuarios/Login (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

En el frontend (proyecto Vue), archivo de configuración **main.js** tengo la siguiente configuración:

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false
axios.defaults.baseURL='http://localhost:49336/'
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Y en el **backend** proyecto .**net core 2.1**  en el método **Login** tengo lo siguiente:

```
[EnableCors("Todos")]
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {

            var email = model.email.ToLower();

            var usuario = await _context.Usuarios.Where(u => u.condicion==true).Include(u => u.rol).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u=>u.email==email);

            if (usuario == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (!VerificarPasswordHash(model.password, usuario.password_hash, usuario.password_salt))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                //Estos claims se utiizan en el proyecto ASP NET Core
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, usuario.idusuario.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, usuario.rol.nombre),
                //Estos claims se utiizan en el proyecto Vue
                new Claim("idusuario", usuario.idusuario.ToString()),
                new Claim("rol", usuario.rol.nombre),
                new Claim("nombre", usuario.nombre)
            };

            return Ok(
                    new {token = GenerarToken(claims)}
                );

        }

        private bool VerificarPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHashAlmacenado, byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
            {
                var passwordHashNuevo = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                return new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(passwordHashAlmacenado).SequenceEqual(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(passwordHashNuevo));
            }
        }

        private string GenerarToken(List<Claim> claims)
        {

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
              _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
              _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
              expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
              signingCredentials: creds,
              claims: claims);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }

        private bool UsuarioExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Usuarios.Any(e => e.idusuario == id);
        }
    }
```

**En el archivo de configuración del backend Startup.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Sistema.Datos;
using System.Text;

namespace Sistema.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        //This method gets called by the runtime.Use this method to add services to the container
        //Codigo video no funciona
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddDbContext<DbContextSistema>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Conexion")));

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Todos",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").WithHeaders("*").WithMethods("*"));
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
                });
        }
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app"></param>
/// <param name="env"></param>
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }


            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors("Todos");
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        }
    }
}
```

**Y el método del frontend (Vue) Login.vue**:

```
 methods :{
        ingresar(){
            this.error=null;
            axios.post('api/Usuarios/Login', {email: this.email, password: this.password})
            .then(respuesta => {
                return respuesta.data
            })
            .then(data => {        
                this.$store.dispatch("guardarToken", data.token)
                this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                //console.log(err.response);
                if (err.response.status==400){
                    this.error="No es un email válido y/o clave inválida";
                } else if (err.response.status==404){
                    this.error="No existe el usuario o sus datos son incorrectos";
                }else{
                    this.error="Ocurrió un error";
                }
                //console.log(err.response)
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Tampoco entiendo porque ese error de **TypeError:err.response**

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

Comment: Con Axios puedes hacer `.then(respuesta => {
                this.$store.dispatch("guardarToken", respuesta.data.token)
                this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
            })` en vez de retornar `respuesta.data` y hacer otro `.then`

Comment: Para especificar la ruta de tu login en lugar de  [HttpPost("[action]")] debe ser  [HttpPost("Login")]